# error '[<-': 'match' requires vector arguments

Tags: raster, r

I created my own function to filter out single pixels or clumps from a raster.

```
sieve_raster = function(x, pixelNum=1, areaThr=0, precise=FALSE){
  if (!is(x, "RasterLayer")) stop("The provided object is not a RasterLayer")

  if( pixelNum < 1L ){ stop("pixelNum cannot be smaller than 1" )}

  if( length(unique(na.omit(getValues(x)))) > 1){ stop("raster is not binary (value;NA)") }

  if( areaThr < 0){ # override pixelNum, calculating it from area threshold
    stop("Area cannot be negative")
  } else if( areaThr > 0){
    pixelNum = round(areaThr / (raster::res(x)[1] * raster::res(x)[2]))
  }

  # remove single cells
  #https://geoscripting-wur.github.io/AdvancedRasterAnalysis/
  raster.clumps = raster::clump(x, directions=8) # Group raster cells into clumps of connected pixels
  excludeID = as.data.frame(freq(raster.clumps))

  if( isTRUE(precise) ){ # Put these into a vector of clump ID's to be removed
    excludeID <- excludeID$value[which(excludeID$count == pixelNum)] # select only values equal to pixelNum
  } else {
    excludeID <- excludeID$value[which(excludeID$count <= pixelNum)] # select a range below pixelNum
  }

  x[(raster.clumps %in% excludeID)] <- NA # Assign NA to all clumps whose IDs are found in excludeID

  if ( all(is.na(getValues(x))) ){ warning("Raster is blank after sieving: try a lower pixelNum value.", call. = FALSE) }

  return(x)
}
```

If I run each line of the function with proper inputs, it works well but when I run the function, it fails (since few days ago) reporting the following error:

```
Error in evaluating argument 'i' in the selection of a method for the function '[<-': 'match' requires vector arguments
```

Running in debug mode with Rstudio I get that the function gets stuck in the following line:

```
x[(raster.clumps %in% excludeID)] <- NA
```

I added the round brackets after a comment in a StackExchange post (that I can't find anymore...): -even if without knowing why- it did the job in that case but unfortunately doesn't help me out.
Anything I'm missing? Any alternative to `%in%` operator?

I'm working on W10, Rstudio, R 4.1.1 and updated packages.

[HERE](http://www.filedropper.com/pl) a sample input raster: I'm using `pixelNum=50`, but function fails with every other value.

Comment: Do you know what data this is getting when you run "in a script"? Is it different to the data you feed it when it works? Because I can't break it...

Comment: I added a link to the failing raster and few more details in the description. could it be possible that %in% interacts with other fucntions/packages? I can't get where that "match" comes from.

Comment: right now I found a workaround `x[ifelse(match(getValues(raster.clumps),excludeID),TRUE,FALSE)] <- NA` but I'm still puzzled in understanding the original issue

Comment: Still can't break it using your sample raster. I do `z=raster("PL.tif"); sieve_raster(z, pixelNum=50)` and I get a raster returned. No error. An (ignorable) projection warning but that's irrelevant. raster:3.4.13, R:4.1.1 igraph:1.2.6, on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can replicate your error, but not with your code...

If I try and do a `raster %in% value` before attaching the raster package, I can get that error. From a clean R start, and calling raster functions by `raster::function`:

```
> z = raster::raster("PL.tif")
> z %in% 1
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
  'match' requires vector arguments
```

If I now attach the raster package, it works:

```
> library(raster)
Loading required package: sp
> z %in% 1
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 301, 260, 78260  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
```

This is because before attaching the raster package the `%in%` operator is this:

```
> get("%in%")
function (x, table) 
match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L
<bytecode: 0x556890f73bf8>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

But afterwards its a generic function which means methods for classes like rasters can be defined:

```
> library(raster)
Loading required package: sp
> get("%in%")
standardGeneric for "%in%" defined from package "base"

function (x, table) 
standardGeneric("%in%")
<environment: 0x556891423158>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x, table
Use  showMethods(%in%)  for currently available ones.
```

What I don't understand is how your function can get anywhere without the raster package attached, seeing as it uses `getValues` which R can only find if raster is attached, in which case why doesn't it get the generic version of `%in%`?

I get identical behaviour if I use `match`:

```
> z = raster::raster("PL.tif")
> match(z, 1)
Error in match(z, 1) : 'match' requires vector arguments
> library(raster)
Loading required package: sp
> match(z, 1)
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 301, 260, 78260  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
```

The safe thing to do is to use `raster::` everywhere, but that makes it hard to use operators (like `%in%`) so use `raster::match`.

```
> z = raster::raster("PL.tif")
> match(z,1 )
Error in match(z, 1) : 'match' requires vector arguments
> raster::match(z,1 )
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 301, 260, 78260  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 3, 3  (x, y)
```

Comment: whoa, I would have never got there...it seems there's quite more to learn about. Many thanks to open my eyes!